# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los nombres que acaban por una letra dentro de un array con PHP7?

Tags: php, array, revisión-de-código, loops, depuración

Yo parto de un array, del cual debo obtener todos los nombres de los que acaben en s y almacenarlo en otro array. Para todos los que acaben en i también.
Creo que lo más efectivo es hacer un `foreach`, pero no tengo claro cómo usarlo. Otra condición más de mi ejercicio es que no puedo usar `print_r`
También he pensado en utilizar funciones, pero no he encontrado ninguna sobre arrays, he pensado en cambiarlos a string pero no sé si es posible.

**Código PHP**:

```
<?php
        //Array
    $array = array(0=>"rafa",1=>"adrian",2=>"angel",3=>"enrique",4=>"dani",5=>"ivan",6=>"isa", 7=>"fran1",8=>"fran2",9=>"diego");
    $elementos = implode(",", $array);
    echo "$elementos";
    //bucle foreach
    foreach ($array as $indice => $valor) {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que es PHP7, una sugerencia es definir los arreglos con corchetes: `$array = [ .... ];` y no con la antigua forma `array( ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar accediendo directamente al array y comprobando mediante el método `substring` el último valor de cada uno de los elementos del array. Una vez hecha la comprobación almacenaras el nombre que coincida con tus parámetros en el nuevo array.

```
<?php

$array = array(0=>"rafa",1=>"adrian",2=>"angel",3=>"enrique",4=>"dani",5=>"ivan",6=>"isa", 7=>"fran1",8=>"fran2",9=>"diego");
$arrayResultados = array();

foreach ($array as $indice => $valor) {
    if ((substr($valor, -1) == 's') || (substr($valor, -1) == 'i')){
        $arrayResultados[] = $valor;
    }
}
```

Posteriormente mostrarás los resultados de tu nuevo array con los nombres almacenados.

```
foreach($arrayResultados as $nombre){
    echo $nombre;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que me cuesta pillarle el truco a los ```foreach```

Comment: Una última duda, con el OR si los dos cumplen la condición también se muestra?

Comment: @ras212 En realidad en tu caso no puede acabar con `s` o con `i` un mismo nombre. Por eso el OR. Que cualquiera de los dos puede cumplir la condición. En caso de que ambos la cumplieran (cosa que sería imposible para un mismo nombre) tendrías que poner && (AND).

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te dejare dos formas como se podría realizar:

Una es con la función [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php):

[Ver demo 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2de39f0f616fb071dff2cb4608ce9f119bf8b821)

```
$array = [0=>"rafa",1=>"adrian",2=>"angel",3=>"enrique",4=>"dani",5=>"ivan",6=>"isa", 7=>"fran1",8=>"fran2",9=>"diego"];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    if ($value[strlen($value)-1] == 's' || $value[strlen($value)-1] == 'i'){

        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Y la otra es más interesante y solo disponible a partir de la version `PHP 7.1` con acceso directo a las cadenas `$string[-1]` o `$string{-1}`

**+ info:** [PHP RFC: Generalize support of negative string offsets](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative-string-offsets)

[Ver demo 2](https://3v4l.org/unKSA)

```
$array = [0=>"rafa",1=>"adrian",2=>"angel",3=>"enrique",4=>"dani",5=>"ivan",6=>"isa", 7=>"fran1",8=>"fran2",9=>"diego"];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    if ($value[-1] == 's' || $value[-1] == 'i'){

        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero de momento la versión 7.1 no es estable, no sé como actualizarla con xampp